# Responsive image with srcset not working in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, responsive-design, internet-explorer-11, srcset

```
<img srcset="assets/img/pages/support-and-services/hub/head1-40w.png 40w,
             assets/img/pages/support-and-services/hub/head1-80w.png 80w" 
     sizes="40px" 
     src="assets/img/pages/support-and-services/hub/head1-80w.png 80w" 
     class="d-none d-lg-inline" alt="head icon" />
```

Above is the code in question. My images are not showing up in IE. After checking the network, I found it's trying to get the image at "assets/img/pages/support-and-services/hub/head1-80w.png%2080w".

So it somehow thinks the " 80w" is a part of the image url and appends "%2080w" to the end. Of course, when it goes to get it, the image does not exist at that location.

I don't think I'm using source set incorrectly? And I can't seem to find anyone else having this issue, and it's in IE only. Please help!

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use " 80w" in `src` attribute. IE [doesn't support `srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Browser_compatibility) attribute, so it will look for the `src` attribute to find the image url. Your `src` value with " 80w" is wrong so IE can't find the right image url.

In other browsers supporting `srcset`, they directly use `srcset` value as the image url. We can use a positive integer directly followed by `w` in `srcset` value so it's right and the browsers can find the right image url.

In a conclusion, you set the `scrset` value correctly but set the `src` value wrongly. It should be `src="assets/img/pages/support-and-services/hub/head1-80w.png"`.

Comment: Omg I didn't notice that. THANK YOU!